# next auth. how to get google id_token

Tags: reactjs, next.js, authorization, token, next-auth

In short: How to get google id token from nextauth?

Details: I do authorization through Google and after that I have to verify the response from Google on the server, after which the server will return its access token to me. A friend who builds backend tells me that he needs an `id_token` and he will check it with `google-auth`. No matter how I try to set up the callback, I can't get the `id_token`. I only get the session token in cookie and nothing else.

If it is possible to do this without `id_token`, please write that as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a snippet of how to achieve that. You have to fetch the account details returned from google using the callback:

```
 callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
    
      if (account) {
        token.id_token = account.id_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
      session.id_token = token.id_token;
      return session;
    },
  },
```

So now, you can retrieve the token by doing something like:

```
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  console.log(session.id_token)
```

So basically, what we just did was access the `id_token` provided by google. We accessed it from `account` and now we are passing to the `session` object so we can use in the client side of our application.

PS> Check your `terminal` during authentication with google. You'll see a log of the profile object and account object inside the terminal.

Comment: This does seem the easiest way to persist data, however JWT has size limits so this may not work for large id_tokens or if other data is being persisted and the accumulation exceeds the size limits.

Comment: @Rikaelus is correct, and I have the same problem, where I cannot simply propagate the `id_token` to my client, because the JWT size is limited.

Comment: I managed to get it working, by attaching the `id_token` only to the JWT and not the session, and then in my customized logout method requesting the JWT:
```typescript
const logout = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    const token = await getToken({ req, secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET });
    //...
    if (token?.idToken) {
        path = path + `&id_token_hint=${token.idToken}`;
    }
    //...
};

export default logout;
```

Comment: @Japu_D_Cret I'm actually not 100% sure I was correct. I was having problems but it ended up being due to nginx proxy limits against too-large of headers. I got around that by upping settings in nginx and I'm successfully adding a 2000+ character id_token to the token in `jwt()` and then adding it to the session in `session()`.

Comment: What's a good way of handling the expiration of this token?